# Clear out old images, any advice?

Tags: plugins, images

I'm working on a site which has a media library that is now 7GB - and I really want to clear out all the unused images.

I've tried using the Media Cleaner Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-cleaner/
But this seems to clear out images that I am using - this seems to be because my whole site is built with Advanced Custom Fields.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could delete images that aren't being used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already discovered the problem with a plugin approach. They will look for unlinked media (images not associated with a post) and remove those files. As you have said, you are using custom fields and you may also have uploaded images inside your post content.

Sadly the only option I can think of is to use a [find](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/find.htm) [command](https://alvinalexander.com/unix/edu/examples/find.shtml) to get a list of all of your `wp-content/uploads` and then reduce that list by removing all images in use. As a starting point, you could try the [WP-CLI database search](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/search/) command.

You'd want to allow for the different generated image sizes given that a `thumbnail` or `medium` image may be used, but you'd want to keep the original + all scaled variants.

It goes without saying that you should have a full backup of your database and files before running anything like this!

I'd be interested if someone can provide a more elegant and robust solution, but this is probably how I'd approach the problem.

Comment: Thanks Alexander! I'll have a think about doing something like that. Wish there was a more elegant solution.